# MultiPath TCP in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tcp

How can I implement Multipath TCP in iOS.

I hope as per the [MultiPath Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201373) we do not need to enable MPTCP in iPhone.

Is there any Multipath TCP samples for iOS

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to enable MPTCP on the phone.  MPTCP is already in use by iOS applications, *e.g.*, Siri.

What the document you linked to is referring to is enabling MPTCP on your *network*.  MPTCP uses TCP option 30.  Many firewalls will not pass unknown TCP options.  In order for your iOS app to use MPTCP, tcp option 30 needs to make it unmolested through the network to your server.

Further, your server must support MPTCP for the phone to negotiate an MPTCP connection.

[This paper](https://irtf.org/anrw/2016/anrw16-final16.pdf) on a socket API for MPTCP has a code sample for using MPTCP on iOS and provides links to opensource code released by Apple that contain examples of using the API.

Answer (score 2):

Multipath TCP is now open for any app in iOS11 beta. See http://www.tessares.net/highlights-from-advances-in-networking-part-1/ for a summary of the announcements at WWDC17. Apple does not expose the socket API mentioned in the previous post.